# Is there a way to extends a TWIG compiled template from another?

Tags: php, templates, inheritance, compilation, twig

After several tests and checks in the TWIG compiled templates, I came to the conclusion that it may be not implemented whereas it is in the template engine from which TWIG is inspired (tested with Jinja2 in python)

The expected behavior is the following one:

Main template:

```
{# 'list.twig' #}

{% import _self as macro %}

{% for e in results %}      
    {{ macro.func(e) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Extended template:

```
{# 'product.list.twig' #}
{% extends 'list.twig' %}

{% macro func(e) %}
    This is the product: {{ e.id }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Another extended template:

```
{# 'user.list.twig' #}
{% extends 'list.twig' %}

{% macro func(e) %}
    This is the user: {{ e.id }}
{% endmacro %}
```

These templates are compiled, but there is a warning in the PHP compiled template for the call of function `func` in the `list.twig` compiled template.
Whereas this line `{% import _self as macro %}` is compiled into `$context["macro"] = $this;`, the use of `$this` in this template is useless because TWIG inheritance just recreate full templates at compilation without PHP inheritance.

Indeed all the 3 compiled templates inherits in PHP from the `Twig_Template` class whereas a full inheritance feature would have inherited both extended compiled list templates from the main list compiled template.

Am I missing something in the `extends/embed/include/use` TWIG feature to recreate this behavior or it it just impossible in the actual TWIG version?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve using this inheritance pattern? Twig for PHP, as you noted, does not compile templates so that the underlying compiled templates use inheritance to implement `extends/embed/include/user`. Unless you are doing more than rendering the templates, it really doesn't matter how TWIG implements the underlying compilation.